# How do I format text before colon in bold Excel 2016?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table that is derived from a SQL database which has a column that i want to format all text before the colon in bold. example text in 1 cell is:

```
Position: Front
emb_type: text
thread_color: Sky
font_type: Serif2
text_line_1: PS
text_line_2: 
text_line_3: 
logo_code:
```

Ideally it will reference the column I and Apply each time we refresh the data source.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Craig

Comment: So a single cell contains that whole string?  Any reason not to use Data --> Text To Columns and delimit on the ":" to put each header into its own cell?

Comment: Yes it does and when doing this it deletes all of the date apart from the first occurrence of the colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this short macro *(for column **A**)*:

```
Sub PreColon()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long, s As String, j As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To N
        s = Cells(i, 1)
        j = InStr(1, s, ":")
        If j <> 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).Characters(1, j - 1).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi Gary

This isn't quite working in that it formats only the first occurrence in the cell of text before the colon.

Any further suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: All of the text i provided is in 1 cell not multiple